# android host files from internal storage(locally)

Tags: java, android, localserver, android-internal-storage

I would like to locally host files which are in the internal storage. I went through google's [webview local server](https://github.com/google/webview-local-server) but by that you can only host files that are in the assets folder. I would like to host the files from the internal storage because i have the ability to modify it which can't be done in the assets folder.

Can anyone please tell me the logic behind it if it's possible? Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Well i dont know what you mean by hosting files but if it can be done from assets then it should not be too difficult to change that code to use files. Which problem do you have exactly?

Comment: For the rest i think that using NanoHttpD is much easier to implement to serve some local files.

Comment: Hosting as in creating a local server using the internal storage files.
There is no file path specified in the google web view local server
The destination(asset folder) is defined by default.

Comment: In NanoHttpD they are hosting only one file in the localhost, but I want to host multiple files in one folder and access them through http.

Comment: You can host as many files as you want with NanoHttpD. What makes you think it is not possible? Would be a bad server if it would not be possible.

Comment: I might have misread it. Thank-you for your information. I Will lookbinto it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loadUrl(String url)` method of `WebView`:

```
String filePath = context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "page.html";
webView.loadUrl("file://" + filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

In an android application, files can be read from 2 locations other than the Assets folder inside the APK. Since these are normal HTML, CSS and JS files, they do not need to be specifically hosted via a local server and instead can be displayed normally inside the WebView.

1. **Internal storage:** URL takes the form of `file:///folder/file.html`
2. **External storage:** Use the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
   method. `String url = "file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "folder/file.html"`

Or else you can use **Ionic** and utilise the **Ionic Deploy** service to update the web-based components of the application as shown [here](https://docs.ionic.io/services/deploy/#summary). This could also be done natively, however you will have to write a service for that within the application to check on a deployment server for the latest codebase and afterwards replace the existing files with the new ones.